# What does the anointing with power mean in Acts 10:38?

Tags: greek, contradiction, acts, christology

δύναμις (from 1410 /dýnamai, "able, having ability") – properly, "ability to perform" ([source](https://biblehub.com/greek/1411.htm)).

1. In the New Testament, Jesus is shown to have *His own divine power* (δύναμις) (2 Peter 1:2-3, 16, Philippians 3:20-21, Colossians 1:28-29, and 2 Corinthians 12:8-9).
2. It is also shown that Jesus is *anointed by God* with the Holy Spirit and *with power* (δυνάμει). ([Acts 10:38](https://biblehub.com/text/acts/10-38.htm)).

   - **What does the anointing with power mean in Acts 10:38?** Other texts say that He has inherent divine power but Acts 10:38 seemed like saying that God the Father gave this to Jesus through anointing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Jesus had innate power and authority is beyond dispute.  However, the NT is at pains to point out that Jesus' "power" δύναμις (dunamis) had two different sources.

1. During Jesus' incarnation on earth, He always depended on God for his power to perform miracles and all else.  Phil 2:5-8 - "*Christ Jesus: Who, existing in the form of God, did not consider equality with God something to be grasped, but emptied Himself, taking the form of a servant, being made in human likeness.  And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself and became obedient to death—even death on a cross.*" It was during Jesus' incarnation on earth that he became tired, hungry and thirsty (John 4:1-42), wept (John 11:1-57), prays for divine strength (John 17), bleads and dies (John 18:12, 19:17-42), etc.  That is, Jesus constantly declared Himself subject to His Father and that all His authority and power came from the Father, John 10:18, 10:32, 15:15, Rev 2:26, etc.

Acts 10:38 is simply another reference to the fact that Jesus was given and depended upon His Father for His power during the incarnation.

2. After Jesus' incarnation, He is described as having His own power and imparting that to us as Christians, 2 Peter 1:3, 16, 3:4, 1 Peter 1:5, 7, 13, 4:13; Phil 3:20, 21, Col 1:28, 29, 2 Cor 12:8, 9, etc; this will be most apparent when Jesus returns, "in power and great glory" Matt 24:30, Luke 21:17.

The point of this distinction is important.  While on earth, Jesus set us an example of how to live by depending on divine power, eg, Conformed to the likeness of the Son, Rom 8:29; Walk as Jesus walked, 1 John 2:6; Forgive as Jesus forgave, Matt 6:12, Eph 4:32.;  Be imitators of God, Eph 5:1; Be holy as Jesus is holy, Lev 11:44, 45, 1 Peter 1:15, 16; Be pure as He is pure, 1 John 3:3; Partakers of the divine nature, 2 Peter 1:4; We are being changed into Christ’s glory (= reputation),  2 Cor 3:18; Pray as Jesus prayed, Luke 11:1; We are to have the mind of Christ, Phil 2:5, 1 Cor 2:16; Be kind because God is kind, Luke 6:34, 35; Be merciful because God is merciful, Luke 6:36; Be servants to others as Jesus was,  John 13:15-17, 1 Peter 4:11b, Matt 20:24-28; Be patient as Jesus was patient,  1 Tim 1:16; Talk/speak as Jesus speaks,  1 Peter 4:11a; etc.

That is, we are not to live by our own power/ability (as Jesus easily could have) but to live by the example and ability of Jesus.

Comment: Your answer is wonderful! However, did i understand your answer clearly? I want to clarify. When Jesus was in the earth, He did not use his inherent divine power but relied solely on God the Father's divine power when performing his miracles. We ought to do the same, not relying on our strength but by the Spirit. Therefore, when "he manifested his glory" after performing his first miracle (John 3:11), it does not mean "he revealed his divine power"?

Comment: As you would presumably be aware, glory (GR: "doxa") and power (GR:"dunamis") are very different words.  Glory (when it does not mean "brightness") means reputation, more specifically, honour as enhancement or recognition of status or performance, fame, recognition, renown, prestige (BDAG).  Thus, Jesus displaying His glory was to reveal something of His character. (I think your reference should be John 2:11?).

Comment: Thank you. Yes. The reference should be John 2:11. If revealing his glory is revealing his character, does that character pertain to his divinity? (We have seen his glory, as of the glory of the only begotten, John 1:14).

Comment: Jesus Glory is a multifaceted thing involving his divine nature but just as importantly, the character of Jesus that so perfectly reveals the character and true reputation of God, namely love and grace.

Answer (score 0):

Re The question asked "What does the annointing with power mean in ACTS 10:38
Answer Think of it this way (kiss- keep it simple).Lets say  that you want to give a "GIFT" to someone you "LOVE".
And please note here I am talking "AGAPE" not an 'affection ' type love.
Not a worldly love.
AGAPE comes from God.
We see  that in JOHN  3:16 "For God so loved the world that he gave--"KJV 
So to give the gift of the HOLY SPIRIT  and POWER which He did for example when thousands were 'martyed'during the Reformation years.They were faithful unto death.And could not have faced up to the terrible torture  inflicted at that time.They had the HOLY SPIRIT to help as we need Him and his Power to 'OVERCOME '
One cannot give it if one doesn't  have it.Jesus received it and we see that in JOHN 1:33b "---the same is he which baptizeth with the Holy Ghost (Spirit).
We see in ACTS  chapter 1:5 "For John  truly  baptized with water ,but he shall be baptized with the Holy Ghost not many days hence"
Look at verse 8 "But ye shall  receive power,after that the Holy Ghost is come upon you--
The verse you quoted is great as it it shows that power. It demonstrates it in action. Quote --"and healing" amen to that  gift.
I would encourage us all to "seek" the what is termed in the BIBLE quote."the baptism of the Holy Spirit.Jesus wants YOU to receive this wonderful  and ,yes,"supernatural" gift.
Just to finish off 
,have a look at JOHN  chapter 14:17 b " But ye know him for he dwelleth with you , and shall be in you."
As encouragement - every single person who associates themselves  with this 'site has the Holy Spirit. (praise the Lord) otherwise right now you could doing something else. But the Holy Spirit will lead you and has.Read Haggai 1:14  and see the Lord  moving on people's hearts  to achieve exactly what He wanted.Here  the Spirit moved.Note that their soul and body followed.
And note  the three fold witness.
He stirred up the Spirit of ---and they went and did.
God gives power.
But you have to seek it.And please be patient. Sometimes God doesn't  rush. Other times it's instant.(a paradox) but hang in there. Its worth it.
See in JOHN 14 he hits the nail.on the head.First he says "with you " ,but now comes the "gift" if we seek it.In "AND SHALL BE IN YOU
Note the thief on the cross didn't get much of a look in there but met  Jesus and was "saved" note LUKE 23:43 "To day shalt thou be with me in paradise.Note   'no soul sleep here.'
Recap:it means "The Baptism Of The Holy Spirit".Is the terminology.